# How to put a hyperlink inside an extjs XTemplate?

Tags: extjs

I have an Xtemplate defined like this:

```
this.Tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<b>ID:</b><br />',
'{Id}'
);
```

Now I wish to add an href like this:

```
this.Tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<b>ID:</b><br />',
'{Id}',

'<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.showModalDialog('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/someAction?',this,'dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px');"> Display Field</a>');
```

But I get a syntax error on the scriptlet. I also think the quotes are creating a problem. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes:

```
'<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.showModalDialog(\'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/someAction?\',this,\'dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px\');"> Display Field</a>'
```